# passing multidimensional array from dynamic form

Tags: php, arrays, post, multidimensional-array, dynamic

I am trying to save data from a dynamic form into a mysql database but i am failing to post the data from the form to the php script that saves it.
So i have 2 arrays:

$angajati i.e.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => gigi 
    [1] => codrin 
    [2] => geo 
)
```

That gives the number of rows in form and $days_total that holds the dates in the current month i.e.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 2021-06-01 
    [1] => 2021-06-02 
    [2] => 2021-06-03 
    .....
)
```

How i did it in short...I have put this in a form:

```
foreach($angajati as $keya => $nume)
{
foreach ($days_total as $key=>$val)
        {  

         <select name="ziua[$keya][$key]" >
               <option value="8">8</option>
               <option value="ZLP">ZLP</option>
         </select>

        }
}
```

in the action script of the form i posted it like this:

```
$ziua = $_POST["ziua"];
```

but when i print it i get this result:

```
Array ( 
    [$keya] => Array ( 
        [$key] => 8 
    ) 
)...
```

what am i doing wrong? pls help.

Comment: Can you share your HTML code where you are trying to print the data @Cilonx

Comment: There is no html code where i am printing the result...just posting the data and then print_r($ziua).The result should be an array containing values of the dynamic form built in the foreach loops.

Comment: @Cilonx  pls share what expected outcome array you actually want